# How to specify beginning-of-line keywords in ANTLR grammars (which also works for the first input line)

Tags: parsing, antlr4, tokenize

This is a question about the remaining problem of the solution proposed for [another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903723/how-to-detect-beginning-of-line-or-the-name-getcharpositioninline-does-not/31910284#31910284) about beginning-of-line keywords.

I am writing an ANTLR4 lexer and parser for a programming language where something is a keyword in case it is the first non-whitespace token of a line. Let me explain this with an example. Suppose "bla" is a keyword then in the following example:

```
foo bla
    bla foo foo
foo bla bla
```

the second "bla" should be recognized as a keyword but the others shouldn't.

In order to achieve this I have defined the following simple ANTLR4 grammar:

```
grammar foobla;

// PARSER

main
    : line* EOF
    ;

line
    : indicator text*
    ;

indicator
    : foo
    | bla
    ;

foo: FOO ;
bla: BLA ;
text: TEXT ;

// LEXER

WHITESPACE: [ \t] -> skip ;

fragment NL: [\n\r\f]+[ \t]* ;
fragment NONNL: ~[\n\r\f] ;

// Indicators
FOO: NL 'foo' ;
BLA: NL 'bla' ;

TEXT: NONNL+ ;
```

This is similar to the answer given in [How to detect beginning of line, or: "The name 'getCharPositionInLine' does not exist in the current context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903723/how-to-detect-beginning-of-line-or-the-name-getcharpositioninline-does-not/31910284#31910284).

Now my question. This works fine, except in case the "bla" or "foo" keyword is used in the first line of the input program. I can think of 2 ways to solve this but I don't know how this can be achieved:

- Use something like a BOF (beginning of file) token. However, I can't find such a concept in the manual
- Use a hook to dynamically add a new line at the beginning of the input file before the parsing starts, preferably by specifying something in the g4 file itself. This I couldn't find either in the manual

I don't want to write an extra application/wrapper to add a new line to the input file just because of this.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a bit more info to it? Does the lexer also produce NL tokens? Perhaps give a more realistic input example: IMO the problem with such simplified examples leave too much room for interpretation.

Comment: @BartKiers, I have added the entire grammar. Note that this is just a simple toy language to explain the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea:

In your `BLA` lexer rule add a predicate which checks the end of the token stream (where the `BLA` token is not yet added) to see on which line the last non-whitespace token was. If that line differs from the current token line you know the `BLA` token is really a `BLA` token, otherwise set its type to `IDENTIIFIER`.

Comment: Thanks. I need to sort out how to do this exactly. I let you know as soon as I have some results.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not going to work because there is no non-whitespace token before the first line...

Comment: Well, if there's no other content (whitespace or not) before the `BLA` token then it must be a keyword, no? :-D